# package require with static lib

Tags: tcl

I am working on app which uses tcl package implemented in C++ and linked as static library (app is developed long time ago). It does following:

```
// Library code
extern "C" int  testlib_SafeInit _ANSI_ARGS_((Tcl_Interp *interp))
{
    return Tcl_PkgProvide(interp, "testlib", "1.6");
}

extern "C" int testlib_Init _ANSI_ARGS_((Tcl_Interp *interp))
{
    return testlib_SafeInit(interp);
}


// Application code
extern "C" int  testlib_SafeInit _ANSI_ARGS_((Tcl_Interp *interp));
extern "C" int testlib_Init _ANSI_ARGS_((Tcl_Interp *interp));

int main()
{
    Tcl_Interp* interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();
    Tcl_Init(interp);
    Tcl_PkgProvide(interp, "testlib", "1.6");
    Tcl_StaticPackage(interp, "testlib", testlib_Init, testlib_SafeInit);
    Tcl_Eval(interp, "package require testlib");
    std::cout << "Res = " << Tcl_GetStringResult(interp);
    return 0;
}
```

When I am removing line Tcl_PkgProvide(interp, "testlib", "1.6"); from main, package becomes invisible. Also I have noticed that testlib_Init and testlib_SafeInit are not called. I am expecting that they must be called from package require testlib. As I understand from docs each package must have pkgIndex.tcl in auto_path or tcl_pkgPath which must contain line 
(package ifneeded testlib 1.6 {load {} testlib}), but here both variables does not contain such index file.

Is this a correct way of providing packages? Is there a documentation related with providing packages using static libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the simplest technique for statically providing a package is to just install it directly. The package init code should be the one calling `Tcl_PkgProvide` — you don't do so from main() usually — and you probably don't need `Tcl_StaticPackage` at all unless you're wanting to install the code into sub-interpreters.

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    Tcl_FindExecutable(argv[0]);

    Tcl_Interp* interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();
    Tcl_Init(interp);
    testlib_Init(interp);
    // OK, setup is now done

    Tcl_Eval(interp, "package require testlib");
    std::cout << "Res = " << Tcl_GetStringResult(interp) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

However, we *can* move to using `Tcl_StaticPackage`. That allows code to say “instead of loading a DLL with this sort of name, I already know that code: here are its entry points”. If you are doing that, you *need* to also install a `package ifneeded` script; those are done through the script API only.

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    Tcl_FindExecutable(argv[0]);

    Tcl_Interp* interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();
    Tcl_Init(interp);
    Tcl_StaticPackage(interp, "testlib", testlib_Init, testlib_SafeInit);
    Tcl_Eval(interp, "package ifneeded testlib 1.6 {load {} testlib}");
    // OK, setup is now done

    Tcl_Eval(interp, "package require testlib");
    std::cout << "Res = " << Tcl_GetStringResult(interp) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The `testlib` in the `load` call needs to match the `testlib` in the `Tcl_StaticPackage` call. The `testlib` in the `package require`, `package ifneeded` and `Tcl_PkgProvide` also need to all match (as do the occurrences of `1.6`, the version number).

---

## Other minor issues

Also, you don't need to use the `_ANSI_ARGS_` wrapper macro. That's utterly obsolete, for really ancient and crappy compilers that we don't support any more. Just replace `_ANSI_ARGS_((Tcl_Interp *interp))` with `(Tcl_Interp *interp)`. And remember to call `Tcl_FindExecutable` first to initialise the static parts of the Tcl library. If you don't have `argv[0]` available to pass into it, use `NULL` instead; it affects a couple of more obscure introspection systems on some platforms, but you probably don't care about them. However, initialising the library overall is *very* useful: for example, it lets you make sure that the filesystem's filename encoding scheme is correctly understood! That can be a little important to code…